# Able to get JSON data in console, but can't bind it to AJAX call on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'm calling for a JSON request through my browser console, and am able to get the expected response.  Here's the call:

```
$.get("/settings/getstates?account%5Baddresses_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcountry%5D=US", function(data){
  console.log(data);
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push(val.name);
  });
    alert(items);   
}, 'json')
```

But when I try to bind the call to a selector in my form menu, I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object json has no method 'apply'`

Here's the same call as an AJAX bind:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#country").bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      console.log(data);
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push(val.name);
      });
        alert(items);
    }, 'json')

});
```

This is in Rails 3.2 -- not sure if that matters?

Comment: did you check if the data returned is valid json? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check that site out.  I was able to resolve the prob, so I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to JS/jQuery, et al, so this was probably a stupid mistake.  I found how to fix it.  I just needed to remove the 'json' reference in the last line resulting in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#country").bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      console.log(data);
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push(val.name);
      });
        alert(items);
    });

});
```